# "Sort by" filter dropdown design issue with multiple options

Tags: product-design

I have a filter drop-down, and one of its sections is for sorting.
So selection happens when the user clicks an option row, but in sorting the same option
n can have multiple values, For example (see attached image), A user can sort by Value, but sorting can happen in both Ascending and Descending.
One solution is to have 2 options for the same value, the other is to have a switch, like I have in the attached image, but since selection is happening with a click on a row the second option is not viable. The first option too is not viable because it will make the drop-down bigger.

How else can this be handled?

[image]

Comment: I also think this question really belongs on User Experience Stack Exchange. You can flag your own question and ask the mods to migrate it there for you if you want.

Comment: Thanks. Flagged.

Answer (score 1):

I would think 4 radio buttons in the drop down --

[image]

or...

[image]

There really only 4 options for the user and they should be able to select an option with a single click.

..... but ... I'm not a UI expert by any means.

Answer (score 1):

Google Drive provides a helpful design pattern. The sort parameter and the direction of sorting (ascending/ descending) appear in two adjacent dropdowns.

So, if my default sort is "filename + asc", then, with one click, I can switch to "last edited + asc", or "filename + desc".